# Geogebra from apt repository silently dies on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, 18.04

Today I ran

```
sudo apt install geogebra geogebra-gnome
```

on a stock ubuntu 18.04. Running the geogebra either through the gnome launcher or the terminal brings up the splash screen then it silently terminates.

Here is what it looks like running it in the terminal:

```
$ geogebra
GeoGebra 4.0.34.0 (Debian version 4.0.34.0+dfsg1-4) 22 June 2012 Java 10.0.1
*** Message from [geogebra.main.Application.setUpLogging]
    /tmp/GeoGebraLog_qrhdpnnfig.txt
```

Here's the log file mentioned from the terminal

```
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:18 AM  
STDOUT:   current views:

Jun 05, 2018 7:52:19 AM  
STDOUT: geogebra.euclidian.EuclidianView[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=20,height=20],preferredSize=]

Jun 05, 2018 7:52:19 AM  
STDERR: XXXXXXXXX Number of registered views = 1
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:19 AM  
STDOUT: class geogebra.euclidian.EuclidianView
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR: *** Message from [geogebra.gui.view.algebra.AlgebraView.<init>]
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR: XXX creating Algebra View XXX
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT:   current views:

Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: geogebra.euclidian.EuclidianView[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=20,height=20],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=640,height=480]]

Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: geogebra.gui.view.algebra.AlgebraView[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@512d92b,flags=16777576,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,editable=true,invokesStopCellEditing=true,largeModel=true,rootVisible=false,rowHeight=-1,scrollsOnExpand=true,showsRootHandles=false,toggleClickCount=1,visibleRowCount=20]

Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR: XXXXXXXXX Number of registered views = 2
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: class geogebra.euclidian.EuclidianView
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: class geogebra.gui.view.algebra.AlgebraView
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: *** Message from [geogebra.main.GeoGebraPreferences.loadPrefsSystem]
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT:     
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: system preference /geogebra does not exist
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: *** Message from [geogebra.main.GeoGebraPreferences.loadVersionCheckAllow]
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT:     
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: no ggbPrefsSystem : systemAllows = true
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: *** Message from [geogebra.main.Application.setVersionCheckAllowed]
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT:     
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDOUT: versionCheckAllowed = true
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.plugin.ClassPathManipulator.addURL(ClassPathManipulator.java:68)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:80)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.main.Application.getPluginManager(Application.java:5048)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.main.Application.<init>(Application.java:612)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.main.Application.<init>(Application.java:467)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.gui.app.GeoGebraFrame.createApplication(GeoGebraFrame.java:288)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.gui.app.GeoGebraFrame.createNewWindow(GeoGebraFrame.java:311)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.gui.app.GeoGebraFrame.createNewWindow(GeoGebraFrame.java:276)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.gui.app.GeoGebraFrame.init(GeoGebraFrame.java:242)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.gui.app.GeoGebraFrame.main(GeoGebraFrame.java:196)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.GeoGebra.startGeoGebra(GeoGebra.java:103)
Jun 05, 2018 7:52:20 AM  
STDERR:     at geogebra.GeoGebra.main(GeoGebra.java:88)
```

I've run ps ax grepping for java or geogebra and nothing seems to be running. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it start with sudo?

Comment: @CyrillC he use `$ geogebra` so he don't have root permission or `sudo`, but I think a more explicit error would have been printed in this case

Comment: Same behavior and the error log logs about the same with sudo.

Comment: FWIW I just installed and tried with `sudo apt install geogebra-kde` and whilst it needed lots of java stuff installed it did run properly. My log was near identical until the line `STDERR: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader`. So, it looks like a java problem to me. Perhaps try a `--reinstall` of java? Mine is `openjdk version "1.8.0_171"`.

Comment: Ah, [actually it looks like a [java9  problem](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011800). The relationship between ClassLoader and URLClassLoader has altered and so the app needs to be changed to accommodate java9 - file a bug report with Geogebra!

Comment: I think this is maybe more of a debian error by using ancient packages with newer java libraries. I just noticed this version of geogebra is 6 years old! I usually prefer apt wrapped packages because I don't like spending my  time dealing with dependency hell. In this particular case it may be easier to install directly from the source

Answer (score 4):

Since I realized that the apt repo version of geogebra is ancient I downloaded the latest version from https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Installation

Since 18.04 is natively 64 bit (at least my version). I downloaded:

`geogebra-classic_6.0.471.0-201805301433_amd64.deb`

Then I removed the apt installation

```
sudo apt remove geogebra geogebra-gnome
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I installed gdebi to help with the dependencies of the foriegn .deb

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

And installed using gdebi

```
sudo gdebi geogebra-classic_6.0.471.0-201805301433_amd64.deb
```

It runs cleanly though the command line is now geogebra-classic.

Comment: Please file a bug report against the geogebra pacakge. Problems don't get fixed until somebody files a bug report.

Comment: For anyone interested - I reported [bug 1775244 to Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geogebra/+bug/1775244) about Geogebra crash on clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @N0rbert thanks I was not even sure where to report it :)